# ASP.NET Core WebApp not building on Travis CI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, travis-ci

Getting the following error on **[TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/petreturcu/WebApp)** when trying to build an ASP.NET Core WebApp.

> Could not find project file
>   /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props,
>   to import. Ignoring.

Builds on **[AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/petreturcu/webapp)**. Is there any way to install the missing file?

Note that I'm new to Travis CI so please include a reference (eg. link/step by step/guide) on how to implement your suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trial and error we've came up with this:

- Put these files into the root of your repo https://github.com/aspnet/KoreBuild/tree/1.0.0/template
- Copy .travis.yml from a aspnet project e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/.travis.yml
- Remove parts you don't want, like branches and notifications
- Make sure your solution and global.json is in the same directory as build.sh

I haven't found any documentation for it, so if it doesn't do what you want, you can just let it install dotnet and do what you want with commands yourself (e.g. `dotnet publish`)

Old answer:

> If you don't solve the problem with xbuild, you can try using dotnet
>   cli. The install script for RTM is here:
>   `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0-preview2/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh`
>
> Then you use `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` (cd to directory with
>   project.json)
>
> Change your .travis.yml to this:
>
> ```
> language: csharp
> install: curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0-preview2/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.sh
> ```
>
> | bash
>       script:
>       - dotnet restore WebApp/src/WebApp/project.json
>       - dotnet build WebApp/src/WebApp/project.json
>       addons:
>         apt:
>           packages:
>           - gettext
>           - libcurl4-openssl-dev
>           - libicu-dev
>           - libssl-dev
>           - libunwind8
>           - zlib1g
>
> I'm not sure all of the apt packages are necessary. source:
>   http://andrewlock.net/adding-travis-ci-to-a-net-core-app/
>
> It's also possible to use KoreBuild
>   https://github.com/aspnet/KoreBuild/tree/1.0.0/template
>
> ```
> script: ./build.sh  //Add the file to repo
> ```

Comment: Seems C# builds are community driven in Travis and are done using Mono. After some digging: dotnet integration is being worked on by Mono -  http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/dotnet-integration/

Comment: @PetreTurcu I just tried [KoreBuild](https://github.com/aspnet/KoreBuild/tree/1.0.0/template) and it seems to be the best solution

Comment: Sorry, do I need to change something in the build.sh? Just copying it over and amending the .yml indeed passes travis but doesn't build my solution (deleted a colon to test).

Comment: https://github.com/petreturcu/WebApp/blob/6af6214217bf66f18ca9b73baf9572372d1321a0/.travis.yml#L2
you are just changing permissions. you need:
`script: chmod a+x ./build.sh && ./build.sh`

Comment: Try adding `addons: apt: packages: - libunwind8` (format it as in answer, comment can't have newlines)

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package libunwind8` tried specifying the os aswell but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117599/discussion-between-petre-turcu-and-j2ghz).

Comment: Try `dist: trusty`